# TeX doesn't apply changed memory settings from local texmf.cnf

Tags: xetex, macos, texmf.cnf

I added my own `textmf.cnf` and have set up `TEXMFCNF` to point to it with `export TEXMFCNF=path:` in `.zshrc`.
`kpsewhich` finds it correctly. My `texmf.cnf`:

```
stack_size=150000
```

When I run `latexmk -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -xelatex main.tex`

I got `./main.tex:6: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=20000].`

When I have this function in a package, that I import to TeX file, I get an error:

```
\renewcommand*{\titlepage}[2]{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \newgeometry{
            top=10mm,
            bottom=10mm,
            left=10mm,
            right=10mm
        }
        \begin{center}
            Федеральное государственное автономное\\
            образовательное учреждение\\
            высшего образования\\
            <<СИБИРСКИЙ ФЕДЕРАЛЬНЫЙ УНИВЕРСИТЕТ>>\\[5mm]
            Институт космических и информационных технологий\\
            кафедра <<Прикладная информатика>>\\
            \vfill
            {\Large\textbf{ОТЧЁТ ПО ЛАБОРАТОРНОЙ РАБОТЕ}}\\[3mm]
            #1\\
        \end{center}
        \vfill
        
        \begin{tabular}{l c m{0.01\textwidth} l}
            Преподаватель                           & \rule{3cm}{0.1pt} &  & #2 \\[20mm]
            Студент группы КИ 20-14б, № з/к 1234567 & \rule{3cm}{0.1pt} &  & С.~С.~Студентов  \\
            
        \end{tabular}
        
        \vfill
        \begin{center}
            Красноярск {\the\year}
        \end{center}
        
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \restoregeometry    
}
```

Comment: did you recreate the format?  (But I some doubts that extending the stack size will solve your problem, it is quite probable that you have a faulty definition somewhere which will eat up the larger stack too.)

Comment: I have run `sudo fmtutil-sys -all`. It didn't help.

Comment: what on earth does your document look like to hit param stack overflow?

Comment: You can't redefine `\titlepage` in terms of itself: `\begin{titlepage}` does `\titlepage`, that you have redefined to something that uses `\begin{titlepage}`, hence `\titlepage`: infinite loop. No matter how big you make the stack, this will exceed any capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error relates to `param_size` not `stack_size`:

```
param_size = 20000      % simultaneous macro parameters, also applies to MP
```

You are *very* unlikely to need a stack this big unless you have an infinite loop that will consume all available stack space. In such a case making the stack bigger will not help.

Comment: When I also set it to `150000`, it raised error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=32767].` Could it be fixed?

Comment: @Intolighter if your document is in an infinite loop increasing the stack will not help, just makes it take longer to give an error. Otherwise 32767 may be the compiled in hard limit (I would have to check the sources, but using more than 100 or so seems very odd)

Comment: I wanted to paste a page of text from command.

Comment: @Intolighter sorry I don't understand your comment. the stack is not controlling the size of an argument (eg a page of text) but a stack of nested unfinished arguments that normally only needs a depth of four or five

Comment: I added function code

Comment: @Intolighter please always provide a full test not just a fragment although as we guessed you have made an infinite loop so increasing the stack makes things worse not better.

Answer (score 2):

It's a basic notion when programming in LaTeX that `\begin{env}` executes, at some point, the command `\env`.

You're basically doing

```
\renewcommand{\titlepage}{...\titlepage...}
```

and this will exceed any given amount of memory, because it's an infinite loop that accumulates tokens in memory and never ends; the loop is entered upon executing `\titlepage` in your document.

Do `\newcommand{\mytitlepage}{...}` instead.